# Google Analytics 4 supports to fetch user data like Universal Analytics do?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

The User Activity API allows a Google Analytics property owner to retrieve all analytics measurement data associated with a single user. Do we have any API in Google Analytics 4 to do the same thing by sending userId or uid and get all logged events relater to that userid.

Doc link for Universal Analytics :- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting

Comment: For GA4 we have [google analytics admin api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1#account_summaries) and the [google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)

Comment: @DaImTo that thing I know I just need confirmation that is there any way to fetch user data in GA4 like we can do in UA.

Comment: As far as i know there isnt one but i have pinged the team to see if there is something in the works or what.